# Sync between UserProfile Store and User Information List

Tags: 2007, user-profile, profile-sync, shared-service-provider, my-site

One of the users has updated his photo/picture on his My Site and it is showing the updated photo (on his My Site) as well as the picture property (user profile property) in SSP is updated with the new url (http://...).

However, the new picture is not displaying in the other sharepoint web-applications. I have verified that the user has already contribute/uploaded a document into the document library in the site-collection.

I even removed the user from the sharepoint member group and re-added the user using people picker window however still the result is same.

I run the "stsadm -o sync" and it did not fix the issue.

Do we have any specific method or command to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PS code to fix this.

$url = "http://hulmossteam:25000/"

$site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url )

$web = $site.OpenWeb();

$myUser = $web.SiteUsers["c1\Administrator"]

$myUserInfo = $web.SiteUserInfoList.Items.GetItemById($myUser.ID)

$myUserInfo["Picture"]= "http://mysite/personal/Administrator/Shared%20Pictures/c781e650-0bc1-4c63-bb47-00f51398fd80.jpg"

$myUserInfo.Update()

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to a similar issue that Andrew Pointed to here

[Profile Sync doesn't filter to all users on all sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135/profile-sync-doesnt-filter-to-all-users-on-all-sites)

EDIT: url now points to migrated site

Comment: the link seems broken...

Comment: It was a pre-migration link to this site. I have edited link so that it now points to correct URL

Answer (score 0):

I seen this frequently, but overnight it is fixed... I think it's spart of a daily job.

Comment: I waited for a weektime however it was fixed and which forced me to find a workaround as above. – Crazy 0 secs ago